# How to use Emgu CV to highlight corners on an image

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am trying to detect the corners on a checkerboard image and then draw circles over those sections of the image. I have consulted with the documentation of Emgu Cv and there are two ways to do this.

1. Is to use the **FindCornerSubPixel()** method of the Image<Gray,byte> class
2. Use the **CvInvoke.HarrisCorner(...)** method

I am using the second method to do this as I have no clue how to use the first method to do this. My attempt is shown below but am getting an exception that

> OpenCV: !image.empty().

The implementation details of my code are shown below

```
var pth = paths[index];
//load the image in grayscale
var image = new Image<Gray, byte>(pth);
//initialize an empty image for displaying the corners
var cornerImage = new Mat();
//call the corner recognition algorithm
CvInvoke.CornerHarris(image, cornerImage, blockSize:3,apertureSize:3,k:0.01);
//save the image with corners 
cornerImage.Save("temp.png");
```

Any help on how to use either of those methods to successfully detect corners on the checkerboard image is highly appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [FindChessboardCorners](https://emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/b0a42bbe-419c-18d2-16b9-77d390042133.htm)

```
var result = new VectorOfPointF();
bool foundCorners = CvInvoke.FindChessboardCorners(
                            image, 
                            new Size(6, 9), 
                            result)
PointF[] corners = result.ToArray();
```

This is specifically for detecting corners of a chessboard, so should give more reliable results than HarrisCorner, but does require you to know how many squares are in your board.

If you need more accurate positions you could then use FindCornerSubPixel to get more accurate positions. I cannot tell if sub pixel positions would be helpful for your application. We are just using FindChessboardCorners without any subPixel refinement.

If you want to mark the corners you can use the [Draw Methods](https://emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/30aafc09-bd3e-d73a-7f7e-3dde74addfc2.htm) with your found corners on the image. But you could also use System.Drawing to draw to a `Bitmap`, or directly to the screen.

Comment: Thanks, let me test the code and see if I get anything significant

Comment: Can you edit to include implementation details on how I can loop through _result_ object to draw a circle over each point. I know how to use the Draw method to draw a circle but how do iterate through the result object? Do I access its array of array method and do it?

Comment: This is because the result object stores an array of array of type PointF which contains the x and y co ordinate for the center of drawing the circle. Shouldn't the detection method just return an array of pointfs which are easier to plot or draw?

Comment: @QingGuo Added example how to get an array of pointfs, just use a regular loop to iterate thru it and draw circles.  And yes, it would be better if the method returned a object representing both the status of the call, and the actual points. But emgu is a fairly thin wrapper around c++, and c++ is not designed for easy of use.

Comment: Thanks let me try it out and check if I get something out of it

Comment: foundCorners is false for the sample image I attached to the post. Please check and advise, Thank You.

Comment: @QingGuo You should not run any edge detection before running FindChessboardCorners. You may also want to convert to grayscale and/or increase contrast. Pieces on the board may also cause issues.

Comment: Okay. I will remove the edge detection bit.

Comment: I have improved the contrast of the image by binarizing it but it's returning false for the FindChessBoard method. Check the updated image for more details

Comment: @QingGuo I'm sorry, but I cannot spend the time to provide step by step assistance, Please refer to the documentation and examples if you have issues. I can assure you the method does work when given the correct input.

Comment: I did it but I used contour detection and then checked if the contour is a square and grabbed the corners to a List of PointF array.